# NumericUpDown doesn't reflect change in bound value

Tags: wpf, prism, wpftoolkit, mahapps.metro

I have a View with a `NumericUpDown` control, which doesn't work like I expect.
Tried Exceed/`NumericUpDown` and MahApps/`NumericUpDown` - same problem.
It is defined like this:

```
    <mahapps:NumericUpDown Width="200" Interval="1"
                           Visibility="{Binding Path=ControlValueQuantityIsVisible, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
        <mahapps:NumericUpDown.Value>
            <Binding Mode="TwoWay" Path="ValueQuantity" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                <!-- With or without ValudationRule - same problem -->
            </Binding>
        </mahapps:NumericUpDown.Value>
    </mahapps:NumericUpDown>
```

It is bound to `ViewModel`'s property `ValueQuantity`

```
    private double? _valueQuantity;
    public double? ValueQuantity
    {
        get { return _valueQuantity; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _valueQuantity, value);
            CommandOK.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }
```

Also, I have a button (Focusable=False) that changes `ViewModel`'s `ValueQuantity` property to '99'
If I simply press that button, or type values in `NumericUpDown`, or click its spin buttons - it works fine.
Then I select all text in `NumericUpDown`'s textbox and type '1' over it.
Then I hit the button - and `NumericUpDown` still shows '1', even though a breakpoint in `ValueQuantity` setter shows correct value = 99.
Why doesn't `NumericUpDown` reflect `ValueQuantity` change in its textbox?

Comment: When you "overtype 1", is `ValueQuantity.set` called?

Comment: Yes, breakpoint in its setter shows value=99

Comment: If you make the button focusable, testwise, will the text update, on clicking the 99-button? I bet it has to do with the textbox editor being focused and "expecting" input.

Comment: @lidqy Yes, it will ... but shouldn't Mode="TwoWay" update it instantly?

Comment: @AlexeyTitov Yes it should update immediately as you expect it. But seems like the event handling in the implementation of that UpDown and the interaction between the template parts prevents the Update in that situation. You could call it bug...

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the button focusable.

The point is that the input field is a `TextBox`, which by default updates the binding on lost focus: `Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.LostFocus`.

So, you have to make the input field lose its focus in order to trigger the binding. You must move the focus to another *focusable* element.